# ADO Queries - Last Three Sprints

Tags: azure-devops, dashboard, azure-boards

I'm building a query in ADO and trying to get list of all of the improvement work items with a tag from the last three sprints. Ideally, I want to use this on a dashboard so need it to roll N-3. All the variables I've tried brings back all work items from the last three sprints or nothing. Has anyone else faced a similar issue.

ADO Query

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

You need to group the clauses. Tick all 3 checkboxes next to `Or`'s for `Iteration Path` (green in the image below), then click the icon next to `And/Or` (blue in the image below)

[image]